# returning part of a json file as a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am attempting to create a glossary tooltip for a website that finds keywords from a json file that is being created by sitecore. I need to get the "Text:" parts from the json file and make then a variable in my jquery so they are the keywords that are found and wrapped with the appropriate  tags. I had it working to the point where i could get console to log that there were 2 entries in my json file but that's it.

Here is my sample json code:

```
[{"Id":"ef339eaa-78e1-4f9e-911e- 096a1920f0b6","Name":"Glossary","DisplayName":"Glossary","TemplateId":"b27d2588-3d02-4f5f-8064-2ee3b7b8eb39","TemplateName":"Glossary","Url":"/Global-Content/Glossary/Glossary","Version":1,"Created":"\/Date(1343987220000)\/","CreatedBy":"sitecore\\rgoodman","Revision":"ae8b3ae0-d0ca-4c4a-9f27-a542a31ab233","Updated":"\/Date(1348137810133)\/","UpdatedBy":"sitecore\\admin","Text":"Glossary","Content":"A bit of test content for the glossary"},{"Id":"3fa51ad4-cfb6-4ff1-a9b5-5276914b2c23","Name":"Abraham","DisplayName":"Abraham","TemplateId":"b27d2588-3d02-4f5f-8064-2ee3b7b8eb39","TemplateName":"Glossary","Url":"/Global-Content/Glossary/A/Abraham","Version":1,"Created":"\/Date(1348148640000)\/","CreatedBy":"sitecore\\admin","Revision":"231284ec-9fb9-4502-ad79-a5806479ecba","Updated":"\/Date(1348148779656)\/","UpdatedBy":"sitecore\\admin","Text":"Abraham","Content":"This is a lincoln person"}]
```

But I suppose this is not of any use as it is just the "Text:" part i am looking to return.

Here is my jquery:

```
function getData(url) {
var data;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: '/_assets/js/glossary.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data.Text){
           data.Text = response;
        }
        return(response);
    });
}


function HighlightKeywords(keywords)
{         
var el = $("body");
$(keywords).each(function()
{
    var pattern = new RegExp("(" +this+ ")", ["gi"]);
    var rs = "<mark href='#' class='tooltip'>$1</mark>";
    el.html(el.html().replace(pattern, rs));
});
}        

HighlightKeywords(data.Text);
```

Essentially i need to return the "Text:" bit of json where data is on the HighlightKerywords function. Where am i going wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is Asynchronous communication, you can't insert its response into a global variable and expect to be able to work with it.

You need to do all the work on the data.text in the success function.

```
success: function(response){
           HighlightKeywords(response.Text);
        }
```

Comment: He has async set to false. It doesn't really change your answer, but ajax is not always asynch.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is not syntactically formatted properly. Your return must go inside of the success function in the synchronous example, and not randomly placed in the ajax object..

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: '/_assets/js/glossary.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
           //HighlightKeywords(data.Text);
           //or
           return(data.Text);
        }

    });
}
```